# clickonce using old user.config after upgrade

Tags: c#, winforms, settings, clickonce

I have a clickonce application that has worked fine for years.  I recently made a few changes to the application.

1. The application used to be in its own solution but I recently added it to another solution of mine with the intention that it will eventually make use of some of the libraries I have in that solution.  (But I didn't actually change any references yet.)
2. I updated the application from .NET 4.0 to .NET 4.5.
3. I add two new settings.

I didn't notice right way but this changed how my application handles user settings.
Before this the user settings have always preserved across upgrades.  Now when I change the settings they will persist until I push out a new version.  At that point all settings will revert back to what they were before I made these changes (and the new settings revert to the default.)

I did some digging and found that in my (and other user's) C:\Users...\Local\Apps... there are there folders for 3 versions

- 1.0.0.0
- 1.9.8.114
- 1.10.4.0

The current version is 1.11.3.16 and it appears that settings are being saved and loaded from 1.10.4.0 but after an update they get loaded from 1.9.8.114.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that for the first time ever someone other than me had changed this code by setting the version to 1.10.4.0 in the assemblyinfo.cs file.  Once I took that out it reverted to the old behavior.

I still don't understand why it did what it did however.